# Why is Fedora 33 loading modules related to Chelsio T4/T5 adapters on my laptop?

Tags: fedora, kernel-modules, hardware

I booted Fedora 33 live on my laptop and I noticed some loaded modules related to what seems to be a whole Infiniband stack over some Chelsio T4/T5 adapters. This is a sample of lsmod output:

```
ib_isert               53248  0
iscsi_target_mod      364544  1 ib_isert
ib_iser                49152  0
ib_srpt                69632  0
target_core_mod       417792  3 iscsi_target_mod,ib_srpt,ib_isert
ib_srp                 69632  0
scsi_transport_srp     32768  1 ib_srp
ib_ipoib              143360  0
rdma_ucm               32768  0
ib_umad                36864  0
iw_cxgb4              258048  0
ib_uverbs             159744  2 iw_cxgb4,rdma_ucm
rdma_cm               118784  7 iw_cxgb4,rpcrdma,ib_srpt,ib_srp,ib_iser,ib_isert,rdma_ucm
iw_cm                  57344  1 rdma_cm
ib_cm                  65536  4 rdma_cm,ib_ipoib,ib_srpt,ib_srp
ib_core               397312  13 rdma_cm,ib_ipoib,iw_cxgb4,rpcrdma,ib_srpt,ib_srp,iw_cm,ib_iser,ib_umad,ib_isert,rdma_ucm,ib_uverbs,ib_cm
```

That's surprising, since my laptop doesn't have any similar hardware. This is the output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 6000 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 61)
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks.